# How to use count method (string class)?? in python

Tags: python, string, count

I want to use the optional parameters of the count method.

I don't know if the problem is a syntax problem.

str.count(sub[, start[, end]])
Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

I've tried:
1.

```
cadena = "supercalifragilisticoespialidoso"
print(cadena.count("l",[0,15]))
```

2.

```
cadena = "supercalifragilisticoespialidoso"
print(cadena.count("l",[int(0),int(15)]))
```

3.

```
cadena = "supercalifragilisticoespialidoso"
print(cadena.count("l",[0,[15]]))
```

Always, the error seems to be the same:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: It's just `cadena.count("l", 0,15))`.

Comment: I don’t have time to give a complete answer, but try cadena.count(“l”, 0,15). In short, the brackets mean the arguments are optional, not that they should be in brackets.

Comment: `print(cadena.count("l", 0,  15))` count the number of `i` between index 0 to 15.